# Ionic Capacitor Gradle build failed after updating android studio to 4.0

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I get the following error message in android studio 4.0 as soon as the Gradle starts running on the ionic capacitor project.

> Cause: org/gradle/api/internal/java/usagecontext/LazyConfigurationUsageContext

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is you question? There's not enough  information to allow readers to reply you correctly.

Comment: update to 2.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in Capacitor version 2.1.2.

ionic-team/capacitor#3003

Please update the Capacitor dependencies in package.json to version 2.1.2 and then in Android Studio click the button to sync the project with Gradle.

"@capacitor/android": "^2.1.2",
"@capacitor/core": "2.1.2",